# Replacing str by int for all the columns of dataframe without making dictionary for each column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

Suppose I have the following dataframe,

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','c','a','c','c','c','c','c','c'],
     'col2':['a1','b1','c1','a1','c1','c1','c1','c1','c1','c1'],
     'col3':[1,2,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3]}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to go through categorical columns and replace strings with integers. The usual way of doing this is to do:

```
col1 = {'a': 1,'b': 2, 'c':3}
data.col1 = [col1[item] for item in data.col1]
```

Namely to make a dictionary for each categorical column and do the replacement. But if you have many columns making dictionary for them one by one is time consuming, so I wonder if there is a better way of doing it? Also how can I do this without dictionary. In this example we can 3 distinct values on col1 for example but if we have many more we should have wrote all that by hand (say `{'a': 1,'b': 2, 'c':3, ..., 'z':26}`). I wonder what is the most efficient way of doing this? namely to go through all the categorical column and replace the string with numbers without needing to make dictionaries column by column?

Comment: What is number of your string columns and length of DataFrame?

Comment: I have 15 string (categorical) columns and the length is ~5000. Your solution works perfect for this size. Also thankfully do don't have many distinct strings for example in each column there might be about 20-30 distinct strings. Would there be an issue of the number of distinct string goes larger?

Comment: No, there is no problem with it.

Comment: If there are 5k rows it is in pandas small data, also 15 columns is small number of columns. So both solution  should working here with same performance (the best test, but I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get only object columns first by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and then for each column use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
cols = data.select_dtypes(object).columns

data[cols] = data[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1
print (data)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     3     3     3
3     1     1     2
4     3     3     3
5     3     3     3
6     3     3     3
7     3     3     3
8     3     3     3
9     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you could avoid the apply,by using a dictionary comprehension in the `assign` expression(I feel a dictionary is going to  be more efficient; I may be wrong):

```
values = {col: data[col].factorize()[0] + 1 
          for col in data.select_dtypes(object)}

data.assign(**values)

   col1 col2    col3
0   1      1    1
1   2      2    2
2   3      3    3
3   1      1    2
4   3      3    3
5   3      3    3
6   3      3    3
7   3      3    3
8   3      3    3
9   3      3    3
```

Comment: if `apply` vs `dict cmprehension` hard to know, depends of data. Maybe if 10k columns or similar it should be difference.

Comment: `(I feel a dictionary is going to be more efficient; I may be wrong):` - depends of data, if large, 100, 100k of rows, you are wrong

Comment: I think all depends of data, so OP decide here

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the feedback. I didn't run any tests, so just my assumption.

Comment: I am thinking, maybe this also depends of RAM, it should be important factor here

Comment: because large pure python dict need more RAM like pandas column.